# principal submatrix of a banded matrix with banded inverse

Tags: matrices

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}}$ be a banded matrix ($A_{ij}=0$ for all $|i-j|>K$) with banded inverse (probably different bandwidth $\tilde K$). The question is, if principal submatrices $B_n := A|_{\{1,\ldots,n\}\times \{1,\ldots,n\}}$ also have banded inverses with a uniform bound for the bandwidths $\tilde K_n$?

Comment: It looks like the [nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullity_theorem) could help here.

Comment: I don't think it would help. If you take the statement and forget about $A^{-1}$ being banded, then it is definitely false.

Comment: Sorry, maybe the comment gave the wrong impression -- I don't think it's an immediate consequence of this theorem; but it might be useful in attacking the problem. Just suggesting a possible line.